# Как вернуть следующее значение массива по кругу?

Tags: php

Помогите дополнить следующую функцию, я так понял `next, end, ...` в данном случаем наверное не подходят так как нужно именно внутри функции и функция будет всегда заново запускаться

Пока додумался до такой реализации и застрял

```
function get_value($last = false)
{
  $array = array(
    0 => array('a', 1),
    1 => array('b', 2),
    2 => array('c', 3)
  );

  foreach($array as $arr){
    if(!$last){
      $result = $arr;
      break;
    }else{
      if($last == serialize($arr)){
        ...
      }
    }
  }

  return serialize(result);
}

// нужно возвращать всегда следующее значение массива по кругу, 
// сравнивая по последнему возвращенному (его хранение будет в базе например)

$last = get_value();
$last = get_value($last);
$last = get_value($last);
$last = get_value($last);
$last = get_value($last);
$last = get_value($last);
$last = get_value($last);
...
```

Comment: Если нужно вернуть одно значение начиная с какого-то, то цикл не нужен. Возвращайте сразу срез массива с заданным индексом.

Comment: @MAX, это как без цикла? можно пример? что то даже образно не представляю

Comment: Еще актуально?.

Comment: @Manitikyl, да.

Comment: @SergeyArchipov вам нужно чтоб ответ был такой: `array('a', 1)`, `array('b', 2)` и `array('c', 3)` - за 3 вызова функции, так?

Comment: @Manitikyl, значение может быть любое (но там всегда массив, оно уникальное и может быль любое количество), нужно возвращать только следующее значение в виде строки serialize(), короче нужно просто получить следующее значение сравнивая по последнему значению в этом массиве

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S. **serialize** я думаю сами сможете добавить :)

Первый способ, возможно самый правильный:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array('a', 1),
    1 => array('b', 2),
    2 => array('c', 3)
);

class TestClass {
    static $array = array();

    static function new_array($array) {
        self::$array = $array;
    }

    static function get_value()
    {
        return array_shift(self::$array);
    }
}

TestClass::new_array($array);
var_dump(TestClass::get_value());
var_dump(TestClass::get_value());
```

Второй способ, ваш переделанный:

```
function get_value($last = false)
{
    $array = array(
        0 => array('a', 1),
        1 => array('b', 2),
        2 => array('c', 3)
    );

    if ($last === false) {
        return $array[0];
    }else{
        $key = array_search($last, $array);
        if ( ($key !== FALSE) && (isset($array[($key + 1)])) ) {
            return $array[($key + 1)];
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

$test = get_value();
$test = get_value($test);
var_dump(get_value($test));
```

Третий способ:

```
function get_value()
{
    static $array = array(
        0 => array('a', 1),
        1 => array('b', 2),
        2 => array('c', 3)
    );

    return array_shift($array);
}

$test = get_value();
$test = get_value();
var_dump(get_value());
```

Comment: Спасибо, второй способ чуть больше подходит, от цикла избавился, сравниваю по ключам

Answer (score 0):

На поверхности сразу два варианта решения:

1. Запомни индекс текущего элемента в переменной (счётчик). После получения очередного значения увеличивай счётчик и дели по модулю на длину массива. Например, в массиве 3 элемента с индексами 0, 1 и 2. В переменной i сначала 0. Функция вернёт элемент с индексом 0, в i будет 1. Делим по модулю на 3, получаем 1. Нет проблем. Тоже самое для элемента 1 и 2. Но вот счётчик получил значение = 3, снова делим по модулю на 3, получаем .. 0! Вуаля, круг замкнулся.
2. Каждый раз когда надо получить очередной элемент массива, берём .. первый, всегда первый, и не просто берём, а извлекаем целиком. Возвращать будем его же. Но перед этим добавим его в конец массива. Т.е. делаем [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php), затем для него же [array_push](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php) и только потом return.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вариант со статической переменной:

```
<?php

function get_value()
{
    static $i = -1;

    $array = array(
        array('a', 1),
        array('b', 2),
        array('c', 3)
    );

    return empty($array[++$i]) ? false : serialize($array[$i]);
}

$last = get_value(); var_dump($last);
$last = get_value(); var_dump($last);
$last = get_value(); var_dump($last);
$last = get_value(); var_dump($last);
$last = get_value(); var_dump($last);
$last = get_value(); var_dump($last);
```

---

Тут будет при каждом вызове новое значение *(но без передачи аргумента в функцию)*. С передачей аргумента для сравнения можно попробовать такое решение:

```
function get_value($last = false)
{
    $array = array(
        array('a', 1),
        array('b', 2),
        array('c', 3)
    );

    if ($last) {
        $arr = unserialize($last);
        if (is_array($arr)) {
            foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
                if ( array_intersect($v, $arr)  ) {
                    return empty($array[++$k]) ? false : serialize($array[$k]);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return serialize($array[0]);
    }
}

$last = get_value(); var_dump($last);      // serialize string
$last = get_value($last); var_dump($last); // serialize string
$last = get_value($last); var_dump($last); // serialize string
$last = get_value($last); var_dump($last); // false
```